# How to find the data of members in next 30 days

Tags: sql, where-clause, hiveql, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write a logic to find a person membership is going to expiring in next 30days. Can, some one help me to write a query in hive?

I tried using:

```sql
select * from db where expiringdate > current_date;
```

But is showing all the records greater than current date. But I need only for next 30 days

Answer (score 0):

You want *two* inequality conditions on the expiration date:

```sql
select * 
from db 
where expiringdate > current_date                 -- later than today
  and expiringdate < add_months(current_date, 1)  -- not later than one month from now
```

Or if you want exactly 30 days rather than one month, use `date_add(current_date, 3)`.